# How do I rehost the KendoUI phone simulator (Sample included)

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, windows-phone-8, kendo-ui

> So far I have a [semi-working demo here](http://jsbin.com/iTApOkuV/1) and want to make the skins change when people click on them.
>
> The [original is here](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/overview/index.html)

KendoUI has a nice demo page that demonstrates their controls in a simulated phone.  They also include the ability to "swap" between phone layouts.

I would like to demo a corporate product for people who don't have phones and think this would be a great way for them to get used to the product without navigating to the site.

- How do I properly extract and rehost this simulator?

Answer (score 1):

They're doing a `$.get` request which is why I think your demo isn't working in JSBin. 
I haven't really tested this much, but you can change the skin by modifying the code in examples.js. In the code that defines the jQuery plugin $.fn.mobileOsChooser, you can replace the click handler with something like this:

```
 deviceList.find(".osName,.osThumb").click(function () {
     window.kendoMobileOS = $(this).text();
     applyCurrentMobileOS(options.container);
 });
```

See a (somewhat) working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/ayajIvE/2#overview-contacts). Note that you may need to change other things to make it fully functional (and you may not want to use the kendo domain for your own demo).